# How to reduce noise Buck converter at constant current mode ACT4088

Tags: noise, buck, constant-current, step-down

Hello i am using a ACT4088US-T ([datasheet here](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/412/ACT4088_Data_Sheet-1714846.pdf)) Buck converter and i made it to run in constant current mode 500[mA] through a Diode (D5):
Everything works fine. It draws 500mA no matter the load i attach to it and the Voltage at FB is 0.81V all the time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT1OlG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But i get noise of about 280[mV] p-p (Peak to peak) max before the diode (Point A at my schematic). If i remove C2 and C3, the noise increases (thats why i have them there).
[image: 250mVNoise]

What are other ways to reduce the noise At point A?

Reading the datasheet of ACT4088, i think i can decrease the noise by using a larger Inductor (L1).  Maybe using a larger C1 would help?
Would bootstraping the output with a diode (Page 8 of datasheet, D2 diode) would help?

(Just for the record i tried adding a large 3300uF Cap after the diode, it didnt help much)

Probe is x10
**Oscilloscope settings are:**

COUPLING: DC 1MΩ

V/div Offset: NORMAL

Probe attenuation: x1

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you are properly scoping the voltage - anything other than a spring probe is going to give false results.

Comment: I am using a casual probe: https://www.gmelectronic.com/data/product/480_480/pctdetail.725-103.1.jpg?ts=1518759537 
Are you saying that i am seeing more noise than there really is, or less?

Comment: You can prove this by seeing what the noise is when you touch the probe tip onto where the alligator clip is when connected to the circuit.

Comment: Do not use the ground clip of the probe because the cable can pick a lot of noise. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dDrt.jpg) is the correct way of probing anywhere in the SMPS.

Comment: I see, this is very informative thanks.

Comment: No matter how "good" your buck converter design is, there will always be some ripple due to the switching. Indeed a larger inductor value decreases the current peaks and can help. Also the filtering capacitors (C2, C3) need to be **low ESR** type. If you still need less noise / ripple after doing everything "correctly", consider **filtering**. I'm thinking of a large value inductor in series with D5.

Comment: If changing the grounding of the probe doesn't appear to help, consider measuring **differentially** using **two** probes. Probe 1: anode of D5, Probe 2: kathode of D5. Connect the grounds of both probes to the ground of your circuit. Then on the oscilloscope **subtract** the two signals.

Comment: *Just for the record i tried adding a large 3300uF Cap after the diode, it didnt help much* No because almost all 3300 uF caps don't work very well at the frequency of the switching. I would use 3300 uF only for 50Hz/100Hz smoothing in an analog supply. A 100 uF **low ESR** (low series resistance) capacitor will perform much better in a high frequency buck converter like this.